# Entity Framework 4 Collection to Binary Column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

one of my entities contains a collection of objects i would like to persist to a binary column in the database and get populated on fetching. is this supported with EF or do i need to manually handle this in my repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to manually serialize the collection yourself and then store the serialized data in a binary format.